# limit post by a taxonomy in the admin

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin, author

I have a site with authors from different locations. I have created a taxonomy called locations and has different countries (ex. Canada, Germany). 
Each author need only to see his country's post for the admin. For example, the author of Canada only can see and edit the post of Canada. Its is just for the admin, not the frontend.

Authors should never ever be able to see any other posts.

It is possible to limit posts by taxonomy in the admin?

thanks!

Comment: How hard is this requirement? I mean on the scale from "author should see posts from country by default" to "author should never ever be able to see any other posts"?

Comment: sorry, I just edit the question, the authors should never ever be able to see any other posts. Only admin users can see other posts

Comment: Are those authors able to change the custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution:

```
function parse_query_useronly( $wp_query ) {

  if ( is_admin() && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/edit.php' ) !== false ){         
        $wp_query->set( "location", get_user_role_location());
    }
}

add_filter('parse_query', 'parse_query_useronly' );
```